# Big O notations of some functions

Tags: asymptotics, big-o-notation

What is the big-O notation of the following functions :
$\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\begin{array}{c}
n-1\\
i
\end{array}\right)\\\\
\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n-i}(3j)\\\\
n^{\textstyle\frac{logloglogn}{logn}}$

If possible I would prefer hints on what I should try doing instead of straightforward solutions.